# Passing dockerfile list of paths to copy on build command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, continuous-deployment

I have a generic dockerfile which runs a python script called "general_runner.py", which takes as argument path to a config file, and accordingly runs another python script in the repository.

I have like 20 services which i want to run using this dockerfile. One naive solution is to create a dockerfile for every service, and the dockerfile would only differ in:

1. The paths to folders/files i would copy from the repository into the docker.
2. The requirments.txt file
3. The path to the config file which i would pass to general_runner.py

So instead of creating 20 dockerfile, and then having to change all of them if something needs to be changed, i want to have one generic dockerfile and pass all the "differences" as arguments.

To do paragraph 1, i need to somehow pass this dockerfile all the required paths as arguments. So what i want is a way to pass the dockerfile a list of paths, and for each of them i want him to execute the command:

```
COPY $path /src/$path
```

At a specific place in the dockerfile.

If i would always want to copy the same amount of paths this process would be easier, but since the number of paths may differ, I'm not sure how to do this.

So i have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to pass into a dockerfile a dynamic amount of paths, and make it execute the specified command in all of them?
2. Is there any other way I'm not thinking about to solve my problem (I.E. not holding like 20 dockerfiles which are all very similar to each other)?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to set the arguments as paths, but since there isn't a constant amount of paths, i can't just write a COPY line for each path.